# Simple way to add html list entries from mysql table data

Tags: php, mysql, html5-video

I've just purchased a great little HTML5 video player, but the way to add files is by editing the actual html of the page.

This sucks, so what I'm trying to do is populate the UL when the page loads with the help of a MySQL table that holds appropriate data.

The list this page has looks like this:

```
              <ul id='playlist1' data-address="playlist1">
                 <li data-address="local1" class='playlistItem' data-type='local' data-mp4Path='data/media/video/big_buck_bunny_trailer.mp4' data-ogvPath='data/media/video/big_buck_bunny_trailer.ogv' data-imagePath='data/media/video/big_buck_bunny_trailer.jpg' data-thumbPath='data/media/thumb/big_buck_bunny_trailer.jpg' data-aspectRatio='2'></li>
                 <li data-address="local2" class='playlistItem' data-type='local' data-mp4Path='data/media/video/big_buck_bunny_trailer.mp4' data-ogvPath='data/media/video/big_buck_bunny_trailer.ogv' data-imagePath='data/media/video/big_buck_bunny_trailer.jpg' data-thumbPath='data/media/thumb/big_buck_bunny_trailer.jpg' data-aspectRatio='2'></li>
                 <li data-address="local3" class='playlistItem' data-type='local' data-mp4Path='data/media/video/big_buck_bunny_trailer.mp4' data-ogvPath='data/media/video/big_buck_bunny_trailer.ogv' data-imagePath='data/media/video/big_buck_bunny_trailer.jpg' data-thumbPath='data/media/thumb/big_buck_bunny_trailer.jpg' data-aspectRatio='2'></li>
              </ul>
```

Pretty basic list. So this is probably a basic thing I just can't seem to find the right answer for.

I'd like to 'GET' the values I have in a database table that read like this (these are collumn titles, the data would be in rows below):

```
 id | data-address | data-imagePath | data-thumbPath | data-mp4Path | data-ogvPath | data-webmPath | title | desc | ord
```

My knowledge is growing for php and javascript, but making calls to MySQL tables is something I'm just trying to grasp.

What I'm trying below is declaring the following variable in a header script:
(taken from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php )

```
 $data-mp4Path = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($data-mp4Path)) {
   echo $row->data-mp4Path;
 }
 mysql_free_result($data-mp4Path);
```

Then with a php call in the appropriate list field like so:

```
 data-mp4Path='<? $data-mp4Path ?>'
```

The output however, doesn't parse the table cell data like I think the script should store into the $data-mp4Path variable...

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

**_ Update _**

With help from @peterm I've tried to use the code provided with the appropriate database fields and respective calls as they should be.

This is what browser output ends up being:

```
 <ul id="playlist1" data-address="playlist1">
                <!--?php
                $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wordpress;charset=UTF-8', 'root', 'root');
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_localTestinglbg_vp2_html5_rightside_videoplaylist`";
                foreach ($db--->query($sql) as $row) {
                    $li  = '<li data-address="local' .$row['id']. '" ';="" $li="" .=" class=&quot;playlistItem&quot; data-type=&quot;local&quot;" ;="" .$row['mp4'].="" '"';="" .$row['ogv'].="" .$row['data-imagepath'].="" .$row['data-thumbpath'].="" echo="" $li;="" }="" $db="null;" ?="">
                </li></ul>
```

The dream of this working to act as a loop and output new LI items to the playlist would be great, but it isn't working yet.

__ Update __

After cleaning up the code, the output between UL tags is now blank. The output is as shown:

```
 <ul id="playlist1">
                </ul>
```

I removed the 'data-address=playlist1' within the  tag.

Comment: You should save the results into a variable and retrieve it in the code below. You can't just echo the data and assume that PHP somehow magically saves the data for you. And you are missing a `=` in your php call: `<?=$data-mp4Path?>`. `$data-mp4Path` in your code is a MySQL resource, not a string that can be printed directly.

Comment: Since you're creating new code don't use mysql_* functions. They are [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use  [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

Your code to generate `<li>`'s using [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) instead of `mysql_*` might look like this

```php
... your preceding html
<ul>
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb;charset=UTF-8', 'user', 'password');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`";
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $li  = '<li data-address="' .$row['data-address']. '"';
    $li .= ' class="playlistItem" data-type="local"';
    $li .= ' data-mp4Path="' .$row['data-mp4Path']. '"';
    $li .= ' data-ogvPath="' .$row['data-ogvPath']. '"';
    $li .= ' data-imagePath="' .$row['data-imagePath']. '"';
    $li .= ' data-thumbPath="' .$row['data-thumbPath']. '"';
    $li .= ' data-aspectRatio="2"></li>';
    echo $li;
}
$db = null;
?>
</ul>
... your html continues here
```

Comment: Thanks @peterm ! I don't have the time to try this tonight, but would it be safe to assume that the 'foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row)' section loops through each table row and creates that entry until there are no longer any rows to make LI items for? Fingers crossed for that output!

Comment: @canacast Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Yes @peterm that would be fantastic. I've posted a followup with the output from web console in Safari. It seems to just be printing the raw code I've pasted in..

Comment: Does the charset=UTF-8 potentially have something to do with it's reading of the table columns? My logic for thinking this is maybe it's trying to read the data in each cell as UTF-8, but maybe that's not what the cell's assigned as.

Comment: @canacast First of all instead of `<!--?php` you should have `<?php`. At the end instead of `?="">` just `?>`. You should also remove an extra `</li>` tag before </ul>. You are not supposed to have it.  Now is **php enabled** on your machine from where you serve your pages? And does your file has **`php`** extension instead of `html`?

Comment: I noticed the code was sloppy too, so it's been cleaned up. Above is an update, but in short now there is nothing being printed between the UL tags.

Comment: Also yes, the PHP is enabled on my local server with MAMP. The filename is index_playlist.php. I've removed the <DOCTYPE HTML> at the head, as this was an html file to begin with. This is all part of an HTML5 video player template.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23933/discussion-between-peterm-and-canacast)